# Pywinauto with Pyinstaller gives KeyError "Formatters"

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a problem with a pywinauto program that when it's turned to executable with pyinstaller, it crashes after opening with the error that is presented in this post.
I narrowed down the issue to pywinauto library and this simple 2 line code is causing this error aswell.

```
import pywinauto
print("This is a test")
```

Then i run the command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile x.py
```

Then when i run the executable, it trows this error:

```
C:\Users\gonca\Desktop\gui\dist>x.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\gonca\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pywinauto\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\gonca\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\gonca\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pywinauto\win32functions.py", line 37, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\gonca\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pywinauto\actionlogger.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\gonca\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "logger\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "logging\config.py", line 71, in fileConfig
  File "logging\config.py", line 104, in _create_formatters
  File "configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'formatters'
[33888] Failed to execute script x

C:\Users\gonca\Desktop\gui\dist>
```

I already tried to import pywinauto (0.6.8) with Pyinstaller, with no success.
I tried also to downgrade the pywinauto (0.6.7), still with no success, this error only happens when i try to use pywinauto.